# Can't read input file while running repast simphony model programmatically

Tags: repast-simphony

First time posing on stack overflow, so excuse any missing conventions. Let me know and I will remedy them.

I am having trouble running my models programmatically. I believe it is caused by imageio not being able to read an image file in a jar or in an external project and I cannot find a way to fix it.

When i run the model normally everything is fine, but when i run it programmatically from another project i get:

First the warning:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.java.plugin.boot.DefaultPluginsCollector).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Then the GUI launches and when i press "Start Run" or "Initialize Run" i get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.media.opengl.GLException: Caught NullPointerException: null on thread AWT-EventQueue-0
```

followed by a host of others that i believe are not relevant here as i read a repast sourceforge mailing list thing where they said with this error/warning the GUI error log is the thing to read. The logger in the GUI reads:

```
2019/03/05 09:12:32,297: Error while initializing edited style
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at repast.simphony.visualizationOGL2D.ImageSpatialSource.registerSource(ImageSpatialSource.java:52)
    at repast.simphony.visualization.editedStyle.EditedStyleOGL2D.init(EditedStyleOGL2D.java:95)
    at repast.simphony.visualizationOGL2D.DisplayOGL2D.registerStyle(DisplayOGL2D.java:475)
    at repast.simphony.visualization.engine.DisplayCreatorOGL2D$2.register(DisplayCreatorOGL2D.java:81)
    at repast.simphony.visualization.engine.DisplayCreatorOGL2D$2.register(DisplayCreatorOGL2D.java:1)
    at repast.simphony.visualization.engine.StyleRegistrar.registerStyles(StyleRegistrar.java:93)
    at repast.simphony.visualization.engine.StyleRegistrar.registerStyles(StyleRegistrar.java:34)
    at repast.simphony.visualization.engine.DisplayCreatorOGL2D.createDisplay(DisplayCreatorOGL2D.java:79)
    at repast.simphony.visualization.engine.DisplayProducer.createDisplay(DisplayProducer.java:48)
    at repast.simphony.visualization.engine.DisplayComponentControllerAction.runInitialize(DisplayComponentControllerAction.java:116)
    at repast.simphony.engine.controller.DefaultController$2.visit(DefaultController.java:214)
    at repast.simphony.engine.controller.DefaultController$2.visit(DefaultController.java:1)
    at repast.simphony.util.collections.NaryTree.preOrderTraverals(NaryTree.java:292)
    at repast.simphony.util.collections.NaryTree.preOrderTraverals(NaryTree.java:295)
    at repast.simphony.util.collections.NaryTree.preOrderTraverals(NaryTree.java:295)
    at repast.simphony.util.collections.NaryTree.preOrderTraversal(NaryTree.java:288)
    at repast.simphony.engine.controller.DefaultController.runInitialize(DefaultController.java:212)
    at repast.simphony.engine.controller.DefaultController.runInitialize(DefaultController.java:383)
    at repast.simphony.ui.RSApplication.initSim(RSApplication.java:157)
    at repast.simphony.ui.action.InitRun.actionPerformed(InitRun.java:17)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The offending code(in the model) for this error must be:

```
@Override
    public Context build(Context<Object> context) {

        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("maps/trondheimv2.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e + ": Image file not found!");
        }
        ...
```

I have tried using an absolute path:

```
C:/Users/USER/Documents/Git/REPO/Traffic_Main/maps/trondheimv2.png
```

and this method:

```
getClass().getResource("C:/Users/USER/Documents/Git/REPO/Traffic_Main/maps/trondheimv2.png").toURI()));
```

I am using a renamed version of the FAQ example to run the model programmatically:

```
package execute;

public class UserMain {
    public UserMain () {};
    public void start () {
        String [] args = new String []{ "C:/Users/USERNAME/Documents/Git/REPO/Traffic_Main/CitySim.rs"};
        repast . simphony . runtime . RepastMain . main ( args ) ;
    }
    public static void main ( String [] args ) {
        UserMain um = new UserMain () ;
        um . start () ;
    }
}
```

The class is in another project in C:/Users/USERNAME/Documents/Git/REPO/Runner/src/execute

I have added the jars from repast.simphony.runtime_2.6.0/lib and added the repast.simphony.runtime_2.6.0/bin folder to the classpath.

My goal is to run multiple models from the Runner project

Thank you for your time.

edit:
Made the changes suggested by *Eric Tatara* and got the following errors:

```
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,452 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: player_play, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,453 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: player_pause, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,454 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: player_stop, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,455 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: player_step, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,455 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: project_open, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,455 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: filesave, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,456 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: filesave16, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,456 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: filter16, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,457 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: reload, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,457 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: exec, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,457 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: folder, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,458 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: folder_open, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,458 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: camera, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,458 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: movie, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,459 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: chart, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,459 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: database, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,460 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: display, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,460 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: info_viz, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,460 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: kudesigner, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,461 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: lockstart_session, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,461 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: leaf, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,462 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: edit, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,462 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: home, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,462 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: info, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,463 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: view_sidetree, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,463 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: harddrive, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,463 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: button_cancel, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,464 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: edit_add, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,464 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: apply, it will not be used.
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,464 repast.simphony.ui.RSGUIConstants - Error loading: redo, it will not be used.
FATAL [AWT-EventQueue-0] 11:04:59,545 repast.simphony.ui.RSUIPlugin - Fatal error starting Repast
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.jgoodies.forms.layout.ColumnSpec.createGap(Lcom/jgoodies/forms/layout/ConstantSize;)Lcom/jgoodies/forms/layout/ColumnSpec;
    at com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormSpecs.<clinit>(FormSpecs.java:115)
    at repast.simphony.ui.RunOptionsPanel.initComponents(RunOptionsPanel.java:114)
    at repast.simphony.ui.RunOptionsPanel.<init>(RunOptionsPanel.java:39)
    at repast.simphony.ui.RSGui.addRunOptionsView(RSGui.java:558)
    at repast.simphony.ui.RSApplication.initGui(RSApplication.java:655)
    at repast.simphony.ui.RSAppConfigurator.fillBars(RSAppConfigurator.java:52)
    at saf.core.ui.GUICreatorDelegate.createDisplay(GUICreatorDelegate.java:189)
    at saf.core.ui.GUICreator.createDisplay(GUICreator.java:12)
    at repast.simphony.ui.RSUIPlugin$1.run(RSUIPlugin.java:99)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (-1) and height (-1) cannot be <= 0
    at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at repast.simphony.ui.widget.IconRotator.rotate(IconRotator.java:51)
    at repast.simphony.ui.widget.IconRotator.access$0(IconRotator.java:47)
    at repast.simphony.ui.widget.IconRotator$1.actionPerformed(IconRotator.java:32)
    at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue 1: you need to copy the MessageCenter.log4j.properties file into the folder from which you are running the model.

Issue 2: The exception you posted indicates that the error is due to a problem with an edited style class for one of the displays. If you create a display style with the editor and assign an image file to the agent icon, the image file URL is stored in the display descriptor XML file which is located in the project .rs folder.  I suspect a relative file path for the image file is defined in the XML file and if you start the code from another folder, the relative path will be incorrect.  I would suggest editing the style XML directly and either use an absolute path, or change the relative path accordingly, or perhaps create a symbolic link in the folder from which your running that points to the correct location.

Comment: Thanks! I got some new errors now at least.The MessageCenter.log4j.properties file was already int the model folder, and i added it to the Runner folder. I found the xml files and edited them accrdingly. Now I get ` java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.jgoodies.forms.layout.ColumnSpec.createGap(Lcom/jgoodies/forms/layout/ConstantSize;)Lcom/jgoodies/forms/layout/ColumnSpec; ` with warnings about not being able to load buttons. Will add errors as edit to the post.

Comment: Maybe I should use another structure, or do it differently in some way? What I need to do is to run 2-3 models in parallel with synchronized ticks and simple message passing. I have one model running and am building another which will complement the first.